# Is there a way to SELECT by a part of a date in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a datetime column in a MySQL table and I'd like to select records that have the same year, month, and day (but perhaps different hour and minutes). In other cases, I'd select ones with the same year and month. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: 5k rep, and accepted an answer against everyone's recommendations.  Quality action :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also do

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime LIKE '2008-08-01%`'

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime LIKE '2007-05%'
```

Comment: OMG NO, please no!  Using string conversions (this uses an implicit CAST/CONVERT, but it still uses one) is so Very inefficient.  It also forces a table scan as this will destroy the optimiser's ability to use Any indexes available.

Comment: If you are reading this, please use the answers below written by Greg or Chad Birch. Too bad I can't delete my old posts when they are accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 12):

The fastest way to do this is using `BETWEEN`, for example:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE
datecolumn BETWEEN '2001-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2001-12-31 23:59:59';
```

Comment: Fast - but hard to get the SQL written correctly.  Fast because it can use indexes if they're available.

Comment: ummm, why exactly is it hard to get the SQL written correctly?

Answer (score 6):

You can use some of the [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to extract/compare the parts of the date you're interested in.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(datetime1) = DATE(datetime2);

SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(datetime1) = YEAR(datetime2) AND MONTH(datetime1) = MONTH(datetime2)

etc
```

Comment: this isn't a good way to do it because you won't be able to use an index on datetime1

Comment: @RoBorg, but when you want to, say, find all the ones with the same day and month regardless of the year (like anniversary dates), this method is really your own choice.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin very true, although in those cases you might be better having separate columns for the year/month/day

Comment: this would have been my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a date conversion done this way before in SQL server (not sure if this works in MySQL):

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 120)
```

(This is just an example of how to convert the date into just YYYY-MM-DD)

Answer (score 0):

There are [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) like year() and hour() that will do this for you.

```
 select * from users where year(lastlogin) = year(now())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  foo
FROM
  FooTable
WHERE
  DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TheDate)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @SomeDate))
```

This: `DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TheDate))`

- calculates the date (in days) difference from date 0
- adds the result (in days) to date 0

effectively setting the time part of a `DATETIME` value to `00:00:00`, without the need to do string conversion or such.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm leaving off the time, but the concept is the same...
assume datetime is like: 12/25/2009

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE SUBSTRING(datetime, 6, 4) = targetYear
AND SUBSTRING(datetime, 0, 2) = targetMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to use one of the following [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in your selection